# How do I animate a geom_polygon in R with gganimate?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am having some trouble using the gganimate package to animate a geom_polygon of the US that I made using ggplot. I have the following data below which I pulled from CDC Wonder:

[image]

I can make a static geom_polygon plot with the following code:

```
ggplot(data = Joined_data,mapping = aes(x = long,y = lat,group = group,fill = 
Percent_increase))+
  geom_polygon()+
  facet_grid(Joined_data$Ten.Year.Age.Groups ~ Joined_data$Year)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue",high = "red",na.value = "transparent")+
  labs(fill = "% increase from 1999")
```

Which results in the following plot:

[image]

Which is clearly far too busy. So I want to animate it over the years and just use a facet_wrap for each age group. So I use the following code:

```
ggplot(data = Joined_data,mapping = aes(x = long,y = lat,group = group,fill = 
Percent_increase))+
  geom_polygon()+
  facet_grid(Joined_data$Ten.Year.Age.Groups)+
  transition_time(Year)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue",high = "red",na.value = "transparent")+
  labs(fill = "% increase from 1999")
```

However, I get the following error and can't find any example on stackoverflow with the same error:

```
Error in from[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

I think it may have to do with the missing data. I tried taking out the data for 1999 and only using an age group with complete data, but I still get the same error above. Any help or direction to a helpful example is appreciated.

AT

Comment: Possible you need a second term in your facet_grid, like `facet_grid(Ten.Year.Age.Groups~.)+`.

Comment: still get the same error

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. A picture is not a very useful representation of your data, since we cannot copy and paste that.

Comment: The dataset is too large to include in the code above, even when I filter to just a single state and age group. I can't reproduce the error with a more simple example.

Comment: You should not include your data. You should make a minimal example that isolates the problem and include those data. SO questions are meant to benefit more than just the person asking, so the question should remove any complications in your case that are not essential to the question.

Answer (score 0):

(Can't comment yet here) Have you seen the `tmap_animation()` function which is based on the map using `tm_facets()`?

See, for example: https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/adv-map.html#animated-maps -- not a `gganimate` solution but should work.